# Sceneform sample project without ARCore?

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

I am looking for a very simple Sceneform sample project that does not use ARCore.

For example with a just a 3D cube that can be zoomed in and out, and that can be turned thanks to a finger swipe.

Are there any examples or tutos like this available ? (in Java)

Thanks !